# Commutativity of Intersection product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am reading the proof of the commutativity of intersection product from Ravi Vakil's notes: [http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~vakil/245/245class8.pdf](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/245/245class8.pdf)

This theorem states that if $D$ and $D'$ are Cartier divisors on an $n$-dimensional variety $X$, then
$$
D \cdot [D'] = D' \cdot [D] 
$$

in $A_{n-2}(|D| \cap |D'|)$.

Question 1:  On page 3, he defines $\epsilon(D, D')$. Why does it follow that $\epsilon(D, D')=0$ if and only if $D$ and $D'$ intersect properly (no codimension one variety is contained in $|D| \cap |D'|$)?

Question 2: On page 4, in the case when $D'$ is effective, why does it follow that $\pi^*D=C-E$, where $C$ is an effective Cartier divisor and $E$ is the effective divisor?